# Filtering database with params using prisma and express

Tags: postgresql, express, prisma

I have this problem in express and prisma REST API app.

I already have route:

```
localhost://3000/api/users
```

who returns all users in database.
I want to extract some specific data from database using req.params. Like this

```
localhost://3000/api/users?gender=female&location.city=Paris
```

So in this exemple I want to get all female users from paris. I hope you understand what I'm trying to explain, my english is not top level.
How can I do this with prisma and express?
My routers look like this

```js
route get('api/users/import', importData)
route.get('api/users', fetchusers)
route.get('api/user', getUser)
```

Comment: `gender` will be in `req.query.gender`, use it to pass to a where clause https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/overview/prisma-in-your-stack/rest#get, other example in official repo https://github.com/prisma/prisma-examples/blob/latest/typescript/rest-express/src/index.ts#L120

Comment: The problem is that users can tap other value like age or username, they can tap whatever parameters they want. So I don't know which doc should I look at.